# Merge Thai letters programmatically

Tags: javascript, thai

I am trying to add Thai letters in HTMLInput value with javascript, but when I send each letter they are not combined together. For example, I am sending 'ท' and ' ี' and want to see 'ที', instead, I'm seeing 'ท ี'. They are not merging like 'ทืืืืืืื' they stand together like 'ท ื ื ื ื ื ื ื ื ื'.

I am taking Google Input Tools for example in this subject (https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/).

Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character is not a combination of `ท` and  `ี`. The second character you have posted is a string of length 2. If you are copy-pasting from somewhere you've probably copied the space before it.

```js
console.log(" ี".length)

console.log(
  Array.from(" ี", c => c.codePointAt(0))
) // [32, 3637]

// 32 is for space
```

The second character in `ที` a non-spacing mark  `ี`. These non-spacing mark characters always combine with the character that precedes it. So, it's hard to copy them or write them as a literal.

```js
console.log(Array.from("ที")) // ['ท', 'ี']

console.log("ี") // this is the second character, it's overlapping with "

console.log(Array.from("ที", c => c.codePointAt(0))) // [3607, 3637]

// string literal with Unicode escapes. 
// 0e17 and 0e35 are hex for 3607, 3637
console.log("\u0e17\u0e35")
```

If you want to paste it in an input, click on the Copy button on this page:

https://unicode-table.com/en/0E35/